# What is the difference between .data.size() and .size() in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, size, tensor, torchvision

I am new to programming and ML and I have been playing around with some simple datasets and neural network architectures. Many times I want to check the dimensions of my data and objects to see that they make sense.

I always use `.size()` or `len()`, however I have seen people using `.data.size()`. I have tested them both in some simple things that I am working on and they give me the same result so far. Is there a difference between that I just have not encountered yet or they are exactly the same?

An example:

```
    print(test_images.data.size())
    print(test_outputs.data.size())
```

gives the same as:

```
    print(test_images.size())
    print(test_outputs.size())
```

which is:

```
    torch.Size([10, 1, 224, 224])
    torch.Size([10, 68, 2])
    torch.Size([10, 68, 2])
```

Any clarification is more than welcome! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [What about .data?](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.0) there is no difference between `.data` and the tensor itself after Pytorch `v0.4.0`. However, `.data` can be unsafe in some cases. Any changes on `x.data` wouldn't be tracked by `autograd`, and the computed gradients would be incorrect if x is needed in a backward pass.